# Pivot a Pyspark DataFrame to get a MultiColumn

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Pyspark Dataframe looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+----+----+----+
|latitude| longitude|var1|date|var2|
+--------+----------+----+----+----+
|    3.45|     -8.65|   1|   7|   2|
|   30.45|     45.65|   1|   7|   2|
|   40.45|    123.65|   1|   7|   2|
|   43.45|     13.65|   1|   7|   2|
|   44.45|    -12.65|   1|   7|   2|
|   54.45|   -128.65|   1|   7|   2|
+--------+----------+----+----+----+
```

but I dont know how to reshape it to get only a register for each date and a multicolumn specifying [variable, latitude, longitude] in that order, so I could treat each combination of variable, latitude and longitude in a separated column.

Making this:

```
df.select(
    'date',
    *[F.array(F.col(col), F.col('latitude'), F.col('longitude')) for col in var_cols]
).show()
```

I get:

```
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|date|array(var1, latitude, longitude) |array(var2, latitude, longitude) |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|   7|               [1.0, 3.45, -8.65]|               [2.0, 3.45, -8.65]|
|   7|              [1.0, 30.45, 45.65]|              [2.0, 30.45, 45.65]|
|   7|             [1.0, 40.45, 123.65]|             [2.0, 40.45, 123.65]|
|   7|              [1.0, 43.45, 13.65]|              [2.0, 43.45, 13.65]|
|   7|             [1.0, 44.45, -12.65]|             [2.0, 44.45, -12.65]|
|   7|             [1.0, 54.45, -128...|             [2.0, 54.45, -128...|
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

And I would like a column with a single value (the value of the var) and a column by EACH VALUE of the latitude and longitude. Imagine making an index of [date, latitude, longitude] in pandas and then unstacking the latitude and longitude columns.

For example, in pandas I would do this:

```
df.set_index(["date", "latitude", "longitude"]).unstack().unstack()
```

Comment: how do you want to treat the two variables? [var1, lat, long], [var2,lat,long], or [var1, var2, lat, long]?

Comment: The [var1, lat, long], [var2,lat,long] way @mck

Comment: So you want 3 columns, date, [v1,l,l], [v2,l,l]?

Comment: Thats it @mck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['date', 'latitude', 'longitude']]

df.withColumn('latlong',
              F.concat_ws('_', F.col('latitude'), F.col('longitude'))) \
  .groupBy('date') \
  .pivot('latlong') \
  .agg(*[F.first(col) for col in var_cols])
```

Comment: Pivoting on "latlong" returns me an error:  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o955.pivot.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef WrappedArray(3.45, -8.65)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset$$anonfun$pivot$1.apply(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:419)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset$$anonfun$pivot$1.apply(RelationalGroupedDataset.scala:419)

Comment: What version of spark are you using? This works for me on Spark 3.0.0

Comment: Seems to be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26403 . I guess you're using Spark 2

Comment: That's it. I'm using Spark 2

Answer (score 1):

I came across this solution:

```
var_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['date', 'latitude', 'longitude']]

df = df.withColumn('latlong',F.array(F.col('latitude'), F.col('longitude')))

df = df.withColumn('latlong', F.concat_ws(',', 'latlong'))
df = df.groupBy(["date"]).pivot("latlong").max(*var_cols)
```

Comment: @mck Can you spot any problem on this solution? The combination of date, laitude and longitude should be unique, so the max aggregation function shoul work fine. Is there any improvement in terms of efficiency?

Comment: looks good to me, but the two lines can be combined to one. I'll update my answer